# Call of member function using bind like functionality

Tags: c++

How to implement a very simple edition of boost::bind, which does not bind arguments, but offer a way to call member function in c++ classes.

Here is my first try:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void x(int i) { std::cout << "Foo " << i << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar {
    void y(int i) { std::cout << "Bar " << i << std::endl; }
};

template<typename A1, typename I, typename M>
struct Binder {
    Binder(I i, M m) : i_(i), m_(m) { }
    void operator()(A1 a1) {
        (i_->*m_)(a1);
    }

    I i_;
    M m_;
};

template<typename A1, typename I, typename M>
Binder<A1, I, M> my_bind(I i, M m) {
    return Binder<A1, I, M>(i, m);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    Binder<int, Foo*, void (Foo::*)(int)> b1 = my_bind<int>(&foo, &Foo::x);
    Binder<int, Bar*, void (Bar::*)(int)> b2 = my_bind<int>(&bar, &Bar::y);

    b1(1);
    b2(2);

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation above does work, and will print:

```
Foo 1
Bar 2
```

The problem is that the two invokes of my_bind returns objects of different types. How can I alter the program, such that my_bind will return a type which only depends on A1.

Comment: I think you'd be best off using `std::mem_fn()`. ... or do you readily want to bind arguments, e.g., the object?

Comment: I have started working on this because need it in an embedded applicatoin, where the c++ environment does not support exceptions or the standart library. So, std::men_fn is not aviable on my target system...

Comment: When I think about this, it is more boost::function implementations I need to understand

Comment: I didn't see your second requirement, i.e., that you want the type to type-erase the enclosing class. ... and I spotted that you, indeed, want to bind the object in your class. To type-erase the object type you beed the moral equivalent of `std::function<Signature>` which internally uses a small inheritance hierarchy: you probably should make these independent tools, too. Can you use C++ 2011, in particular variadic templates? Without variadic templates this is somewhat of a typing exercise.

Comment: No c++2011, and no variadic templates. But as long as I only want to support one argument, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the two invokes of my_bind returns objects of different types. How can I alter the program, such that my_bind will return a type which only depends on A1.

It is possible to do with [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).

In short:

1. Create **Abstract** class with interface you like to have. It may have some template parameters. (AbstractBinder in below code)
2. Create **Concrete** class which implements this interface. Concrete class may have more template arguments than interface. (Binder class below)
3. Create **Holder** class with template constructor - which creates **Concrete** class, but stores only pointer to it's base **Abstract** class. So, **Holder** class has only template parameters required for Abstract interface, while its constructor has all the rest template parameters required for **Concrete** class. (BinderHolder class below)

[live demo](http://ideone.com/JLpAkj)

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    BinderHolder<int> b1 = my_bind<int>(&foo, &Foo::x);
    BinderHolder<int> b2 = my_bind<int>(&bar, &Bar::y);

    b1(1);
    b2(2);
}
```

Full code:

```
template<typename A1>
struct AbstractBinder
{
    virtual void call(A1 a1)=0;
    virtual AbstractBinder<A1> *clone()=0;
    virtual ~AbstractBinder(){}
};

template<typename A1, typename I, typename M>
struct Binder : AbstractBinder<A1>
{
    Binder(I i, M m) : i_(i), m_(m) { }
    void call(A1 a1)
    {
        (i_->*m_)(a1);
    }
    virtual AbstractBinder<A1> *clone()
    {
        return new Binder(*this);
    }
    I i_;
    M m_;
};

template<typename A1>
class BinderHolder
{
    AbstractBinder<A1> *ptr;
    BinderHolder &operator=(const BinderHolder&);
public:
    template<typename I, typename M>
    BinderHolder(I i, M m)
        : ptr(new Binder<A1,I,M>(i,m))
    {
    }
    BinderHolder(const BinderHolder &rhs)
        : ptr(rhs.ptr->clone())
    {
    }
    ~BinderHolder()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
    void operator()(A1 a1)
    {
        ptr->call(a1);
    }
};

template<typename A1, typename I, typename M>
BinderHolder<A1> my_bind(I i, M m) {
    return BinderHolder<A1>(i, m);
}

#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void x(int i) { std::cout << "Foo " << i << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar {
    void y(int i) { std::cout << "Bar " << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    BinderHolder<int> b1 = my_bind<int>(&foo, &Foo::x);
    BinderHolder<int> b2 = my_bind<int>(&bar, &Bar::y);

    b1(1);
    b2(2);
}
```

P.S. If you are sure, that all your **Concrete** classes would have same size, then you can replace heap allocations with placement new inside to fixed size buffer, and add static_assert for safety.